# VCPKG: How do you build **all of Boost** with ICU support

Tags: boost, vcpkg

The following command builds boost using VCPKG.

```
vcpkg install boost:x64-windows boost:x64-windows
```

This command builds **all of Boost**. Specifically it builds the following packages: boost-accumulators, boost-algorithm, boost-align, boost-any, boost-array, boost-asio, boost-assert, boost-assign, boost-atomic, boost-beast, boost-bimap, boost-bind, boost-callable-traits, boost-chrono, boost-circular-buffer, boost-compatibility, boost-compute, boost-concept-check, boost-config, boost-container, boost-container-hash, boost-context (!uwp), boost-contract (!arm), boost-conversion, boost-convert, boost-core, boost-coroutine (!uwp), boost-coroutine2, boost-crc, boost-date-time, boost-detail, boost-disjoint-sets, boost-dll, boost-dynamic-bitset, boost-endian, boost-exception, boost-fiber (windows), boost-filesystem (!uwp), boost-flyweight, boost-foreach, boost-format, boost-function, boost-functional, boost-function-types, boost-fusion, boost-geometry, boost-gil, boost-graph, boost-graph-parallel, boost-hana, boost-heap, boost-histogram, boost-hof, boost-icl, boost-integer, boost-interprocess, boost-intrusive, boost-io, boost-iostreams (!uwp), boost-iterator, boost-lambda, boost-lexical-cast, boost-locale (!uwp), boost-local-function, boost-lockfree, boost-log (!uwp), boost-logic, boost-math, boost-metaparse, boost-move, boost-mp11, boost-mpl, boost-msm, boost-multiprecision, boost-multi-array, boost-multi-index, boost-numeric-conversion, boost-interval, boost-odeint, boost-ublas, boost-safe-numerics, boost-optional, boost-outcome, boost-parameter, boost-parameter-python (windows), boost-phoenix, boost-polygon, boost-poly-collection, boost-pool, boost-predef, boost-preprocessor, boost-process, boost-program-options, boost-property-map, boost-property-tree, boost-proto, boost-ptr-container, boost-python (windows), boost-qvm, boost-random, boost-range, boost-ratio, boost-rational, boost-regex, boost-numeric-conversion, boost-interval, boost-odeint, boost-ublas, boost-safe-numerics, boost-scope-exit, boost-serialization, boost-signals2, boost-smart-ptr, boost-sort, boost-spirit, boost-stacktrace (!uwp), boost-statechart, boost-static-assert, boost-system, boost-test (!uwp), boost-thread, boost-throw-exception, boost-timer, boost-tokenizer, boost-tti, boost-tuple, boost-typeof, boost-type-erasure (!arm), boost-type-index, boost-type-traits, boost-units, boost-unordered, boost-utility, boost-uuid, boost-variant, boost-variant2, boost-vmd, boost-wave (!uwp), boost-winapi, boost-xpressive, and boost-yap.

The problem is that this command does not build Boost with ICU support.

The "vcpkg search" command contains the following entries that are relevant.

```
boost                1.71.0           Peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries
boost-locale         1.71.0           Boost locale module
boost-locale[icu]                     ICU backend for Boost.Locale
boost-regex          1.71.0           Boost regex module
boost-regex[icu]                      ICU backend for Boost.Regex
```

The following does not work since it generates errors.

```
vcpkg install boost[icu]:x64-windows boost[icu]:x64-windows
```

The following builds with ICU support but it does not build **all of Boost**.

```
vcpkg install boost-locale[icu]:x64-windows boost-locale[icu]:x64-windows boost-regex[icu]:x64-windows boost-regex[icu]:x64-windows
```

Building boost-locale builds the following components: boost-locale, boost-assert, boost-build, boost-config, boost-function, boost-integer, boost-iterator, boost-modular-build-helper, boost-smart-ptr, boost-static-assert, boost-system, boost-thread, boost-type-traits, boost-unordered, and boost-vcpkg-helpers.

Building boost-regex builds the following components: boost-regex, boost-assert, boost-build, boost-compatibility, boost-concept-check, boost-config, boost-container-hash, boost-core, boost-detail, boost-integer, boost-iterator, boost-modular-build-helper, boost-mpl, boost-predef, boost-smart-ptr, boost-static-assert, boost-throw-exception, boost-type-traits, boost-utility, and boost-vcpkg-helpers.

Both boost-locale and boost-regex leave out components such as boost-accumulators.

Installing boost first and then installing boost-locale and boost-regex causes some sort of do you want to rebuild message.

There should be just one command to build **all of Boost** with ICU support without rebuild nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is possible to build all of Boost while using ICU for those components that support the ICU feature, as follows.

> ./vcpkg install boost-locale[icu] boost-regex[icu] boost --triplet x64-windows --recurse

Source: [How do I build boost with ICU support without having to build most components of boost twice?](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/8687#issuecomment-545108163)